# Excluding some URLs from Google search using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, arrays, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My task is to get the URL of a company from Google search. Example: If company is "facoboom Sachs", I should return the url "facebook.com". I'm approching it in a way where I find all the links in search and use just the first url (see code below):

Comment: @arundeepchohan can you show me how to do that? where would i write that?

Comment: But why are you using find_all instead of find.

Comment: @arundeepchohan, no particular reason. I'm still confused how to write what you said in code. Could you help me?

Comment: @arundeepchohan, I edited the question accordingly. still an error.

Comment: url.contents[0] is a string  you can compare another string to check inside it,

Comment: @arundeepchohan I edited the question now. I think I did what you said right but there's another for loop, where I think I still need to change code. Any ideas?

Comment: if not url then append.

Comment: @arundeepchohan what? I'm sorry for repeated questions but I'm new to this. Could you identify what I did wrong? There are no bugs but I'm still getting LinkedIn and Wiki links in urls. I edited the question so you can see more code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using a `user-agent` to fake real user visit (see `headers` in the code) otherwise, Google will block your request eventually.

Code:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'facebook Sachs'}

html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search',
                    headers=headers,
                    params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Container where needed data located
for container in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
   # Grabbing link itself
   link = container.a['href']
   print(link)
```

Output:

```
https://www.facebook.com/SACHSofficial/
https://www.facebook.com/SachsPerformanceOfficial/
https://www.facebook.com/jeffrey.sachs
https://www.facebook.com/SachsArtsPhilly/
https://www.facebook.com/public/John-Sachs
https://m.facebook.com/SACHSofficial/photos/?ref=page_internal&mt_nav=0
https://www.facebook.com/SachsMedia/
https://www.facebook.com/goldmansachs/
https://www.facebook.com/teamsachs
https://www.facebook.com/SachsAssociates/
```

Alternatively, you can do it using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "facebook Sachs",
  "google_domain": "google.com",

}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  link = result['link']
  print(link)
```

Output:

```
https://www.facebook.com/SACHSofficial/
https://www.facebook.com/SachsPerformanceOfficial/
https://www.facebook.com/jeffrey.sachs
https://www.facebook.com/public/John-Sachs
https://m.facebook.com/SACHSofficial/photos/?ref=page_internal&mt_nav=0
https://www.facebook.com/teamsachs
https://www.facebook.com/SachsMedia/
https://www.facebook.com/goldmansachs/
https://www.facebook.com/SachsArtsPhilly/
https://www.facebook.com/SachsAssociates/
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for the `url.contents[0]` in a list of urls that you don't want to get by using `not` in init to get result other than list mentioned.

Code.

```
for i in range(1):
    # retrieve urls
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for url in soup.find_all(class_='iUh30'):
        if url.contents[0] not in ['www.instahyre.com', 'in.linkedin.com', 'en.wikipedia.org']:
            one_urls.append(url.contents[0])
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past and I got this:

```
import requests
import googlesearch

def gsearch_scraper(query, location, country, stop):

  """ This function automates Google searches and
  returns a list of URL's from each result."""

  # Add retries:
  for retry in range(5):

    try:

      # Try making a request:
      stop = int(stop)
      num = 10
      pause = 10.0
      fquery = query + ' ' + location
      print('Attemping connection to the web server...\n')

      # Make requests using the free API:
      response = googlesearch.search(
          query = fquery,
          country = country,
          stop = stop,
          num = num,
          pause = pause,
          )
      
      # Store Query Results:
      print('Storing URL Addresses from Results...\n')
      results = []

      for r in response:
        results.append(r)
        print('{} out of {} results have been fetched. Please wait...'\
              .format(
                  len(results),
                  stop)
              )
      
      print('\nSuccess! End of Script.')
      return results

    except:
      print("Failed to Process Page...\n\nEnd of Script.")
      return []
```

What it does is to automate google searches. I pass a list of company names using a for loop. You can specify for each company name, how many results you want per query. In return, it will give you a list of all the URL's that it collected for that company. You can also add location like `'New York City, NY'` for better results as well as specifying a country.

Example:

```
gsearch_scraper('goldman sachs', 'US', 'US', 5)

Output:

Attemping connection to the web server...

Storing URL Addresses from Results...

1 out of 5 results have been fetched. Please wait...
2 out of 5 results have been fetched. Please wait...
3 out of 5 results have been fetched. Please wait...
4 out of 5 results have been fetched. Please wait...
5 out of 5 results have been fetched. Please wait...

Success! End of Script.
['https://www.goldmansachs.com/',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_Sachs',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_Sachs#History',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_Sachs#Current_operations',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_Sachs#Philanthropy']
```

Then, to the results you could apply some regex to extract the URL's you need or to exclude the ones you don't need.